# DRF - Filters in ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my models an User is related with its Profile, which has Companies. In order to serialize them I want that if the user who makes the request is_staff, then the serializer must return all the companies, not only the ones s/he has through the relationship in the model.

What's the proper way to...:

1) Check if the user is staff.
2) Return all the companies if user is staff or return the companies of the profile related with the user.

I guess the best way to deal with this would be check in *BProfileSerializerRelated* if the user is staff and then add something like this:

```
company = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_companies')

    def get_companies(self, obj):
        companies = Company.objects.all()
        serializer = CompanySerializer(instance=companies, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

My current code doesn't take into account if the user is staff so return just the companies related with that user:

**models.py**

```
class BUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class BProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('BUser')
    company = models.ForeignKey('BCompany')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class BCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(BProfile, related_name='companies', blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user_detail(request):
    serializer = BUserSerializerRelated(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BUserSerializerRelated(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bprofile_set = BProfileSerializerRelated(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BUser
        fields = ('id', 'bprofile_set', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class BProfileSerializerRelated(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    dealer_companies = CompanySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BProfile
        fields = ('id', 'dealer_companies', 'company', 'groups')


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sites = SiteSerializer(many=True)
    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'dealer','name', 'cif', 'sites', 'services')
```

Answer (score 2):

Serializer has `request` object in his context dict. So you can get the current user from there.

```
 def get_companies(self, obj):
     user = self.context['request'].user
     if user.is_staff:
         serializer = CompanySerializer(Company.objects.all(), many=True)
     else:
         serializer = CompanySerializer(instance=companies, many=True)
     return serializer.data
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer : "user = self.context['request'].user"

Answer (score 0):

To access request object in serializer you need to pass it context dict while initializing serializer i.e in your `views.py`

```
serializer = BUserSerializerRelated(request.user, context={'request': self.request})
```

then in your `serializers.py`, you can access request user object like

```
user = self.context['request'].user
```